# Php insert into fails and i cant see any error

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to insert some data to my database but the simple insert query is tricking me.

Here is what i got atm:

```
$insert = $this->db->execute('INSERT INTO `items` SET `class`=? `player`=? `name`=? `value1`=? `value2`=? `value3`=? `value4`=? `value5`=? WHERE `id`=?', array($item->class, $player->id, $item->name, $item->value1, $item->value2, $item->value3, $item->value4, $item->value5, $player->id));
```

Also tried:

```
$insert = $this->db->execute('INSERT INTO `items` `class`=? `player`=? `name`=? `value1`=? `value2`=? `value3`=? `value4`=? `value5`=?', array($item->class, $player->id, $item->name, $item->value1, $item->value2, $item->value3, $item->value4, $item->value5));
```

I hope some1 can see my mistake

Best regards

Comment: Separate the columns with a comma. Also, what's with the "where" in an insert? THere's nor record yet, what does the where accomplish? Did you read mysql documentation for INSERT statements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats because you use the `UPDATE` Syntaxe not the `INSERT`

The insert statement should be:

```
Insert into TABLE_NAME ( list of fields goes here separeted by , ) 
                values ( the values, which in your case, is prepared. )
```

So in your case it should be:

```
$insert = $this->db->execute('INSERT INTO 
                  `items` ( `class`, `player`, `name`, `value1`, `value2`,
                            `value3`, `value4`, `value5`, `id` ) 
                  values (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? )', 
        array($item->class, $player->id, $item->name, $item->value1, 
              $item->value2, $item->value3, $item->value4, 
              $item->value5, $player->id)  );
```

And this is a suggestion. Looking to your structure you should consider to create a new table to store the values and with an FK to items table. That way you only have values that needed.

And another plus. Consider in not to user `class` as attribute name as it is an reserved word.

Comment: I tried to use your code but it doesnt get inserted. Thanks alot for your responses

Comment: Your php.ini is configured to show errors? display_errors = YES and the other parameter I don't remeber. Look for E_ALL and change the setting to this option.

Comment: It works. It was my mistake in calling player->id into the table. the id was overwriting the id in items.